# Socket.IO + SSL без указания порта

Tags: node.js, socket.io

Socket.IO установлен и прекрасно работает без указания порта по обычному подключению (без SSL), т.е.:

```
socket = io('ws://domain.ru')
```

прекрасно работает.

Но вот после подключения SSL, со стороны браузера к сокету устанавливается соединение только при явном указании порта, т.е.:

```
socket = io('wss://domain.ru:80')
```

работает, а вот такой вариант, к сожалению, не работает:

```
socket = io('wss://domain.ru')
```

Вопрос: почему?

На сервере кроме самой ОС и NodeJS с модулями ничего нет.
netstat говорит, что 80 порт занят NodeJS. Вроде как всё должно работать, но нет.

Comment: Потому что SSL — это порт 443

Comment: Можете в ответ перевести?
Выберу. Ибо так элементарно, но..